# Finding number of Odd/Even/Negative numbers in a BST in C

Tags: c, recursion, binary-search-tree

I'm writing a function that finds the number of Odd/even/negative numbers in a BST. You pass in a tree and a pointer to a function.

```
int countIf (treelink tree, int (*pred)(TreeItem)) {
    if ( tree == NULL ) return 0;
    return (*pred)(tree->item) + countIf(tree->left,pred) + countIf(tree->right,pred);
}
```

the function pointer pred can be something like:

```
int isEven (TreeItem n) {
return !(n%2);
}

int isOdd (TreeItem n) {
    return n%2;
}

int isNegative (TreeItem n) {
    return (n < 0);
}
```

why is the code for countIF not working? it is only working with some cases, not all.
thank you

it is working with this set of numbers: 7 5 11 3 6 9 15 1 4 8 10 14 16
but not with this: 7 -5 11 -9 3 10 15 1 4 8 14 16 6

Comment: what is the return value of `n % 2` if `n` is negative?! Also: `pred(tree->item)`. The [function call operator is defined **only** on pointers-to-function](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.2p1). Functions decay to pointers to functions.

Comment: Also the downvote for not producing a proper [mcve], including: presenting a failing case.

Comment: Thank you, my problem was with isOdd and isEven functions, not the countIf function. and I'm kinda new here so next time will include examples

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Good point, `isOdd` will return `-1` for negative odd numbers.  Using `!!(n%2)` would fix it, or even just `n&1`.

Comment: @Billi it is still not minimal. What you should do is to find out even a minimal *test case*. And produce a minimal runnable program. In the end you'd have found out that `isOdd` returns `-1` sometimes and would have asked about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of the `n % 2` is `-1` if `n` is negative. Then when you use `isOdd` over negative numbers then every negative odd number will *subtract* one from the total count.

There are at least 3 possible fixes:

- use `& 1` (which assumes 2's complement)
- use `!!` to invert it as a boolean and then invert again (will force it to 0 or 1)
- calculate the modulo on the absolute value: `abs(n) % 2`. This would work for moduli beyond 2. Doesn't work if the system uses 2's complement and value equals `INT_MIN` (thanks @user694733).
- calculate the `abs` of the remainder: `abs(n % 2)`, should work even in `INT_MIN` case.

---

The reason for `(-1) % 2` producing `-1` is in [C11 6.5.5p6](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.5p6):

> 6. When integers are divided, the result of the `/` operator is the algebraic quotient with any fractional part discarded. If the quotient `a/b` is representable, the expression `(a/b)*b + a%b` shall equal `a`; otherwise, the behavior of both `a/b` and `a%b` is undefined.

Now, given `a = -1` and `b = 2` the truncation means that `(-1) / 2` produces `-0.5` and with the decimals *truncated* the effect is the same as rounding *towards zero*, therefore the result is `0`. Now, since `((-1) / 2) * 2 + (-1) % 2` must equal `-1`; and `(-1) / 2` is 0, therefore `((-1) / 2) * 2` is 0, then `0 + (-1) % 2` is `(-1) % 2` and this by the rule must evaluate to `-1`.

Comment: I'm not too keen on `abs` method: It won't work with `INT_MIN` on 2's complement.

Comment: @user694733 well, least of the worries :D